# Merging tables in excel using power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

im using a certain config of tables to generate a cascading dropdown list that looks as such:
[image]

I wanna merge these tables to look as such using excels powerquery:

[image]

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Starting with “I want” is not the best way...

Comment: This is called unpivot in powerquery. You will just need the green table, and then you will select all columns in the powerquery editor and select "unpivot".

Comment: @Hooded0ne would I be able to do unpivot even though they are all separate tables?

Comment: @SolarMike i have tried index and merging in powerquery

Comment: Is the data above just an example? Is every column a listobject? Is every listobject a result of a query in powerquery? If yes, how do the source data look like? And why do you put it in different tables? Please edit your post accordingly otherwise it is just not clear enough what your issue is.

Comment: @Majid Alashari all the data you need is in the second table. For example, the word "food" is found in the second table. You just need to change the layout of the second table. Powerquery had a built in function for this called unpivot

Comment: the top photo is multiple tables next to each other that are used to generate cascading drop down menu that's why they are setup that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each dropdown list is a different table, you have to create a list of all the tables.

Creating a list of tables for PQ to operate on can be tricky.

In my example, they were named `Table19` - `Table26` so I used the `List.Generate` function to do that.  But there are other ways to generate such a list, including just hard-coding it.

Then it's just a matter of reading in all the tables, unpivoting and expanding.

See the comments in the code for better understanding.

**M Code**

```
let
    //create a list of the relevant table names
    //  and create a column of the names
    //many ways to do this
    //Since mine are table19-26, I do it like this:

    tableNames = List.Generate(
            ()=>[Table Name = "Table" & "19", IDX=20],
            each [IDX] < 28,
            each [Table Name = "Table" & Text.From([IDX]), IDX = [IDX]+1],
            each [Table Name]
    ),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(tableNames, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),

//Add custom column containing the actual table referred to in column1
//then delete the table names column
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Tables", each Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=[Column1]]}[Content]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Column1"}),

//add custom column to unpivot each of the tables
//then remove the original tables column and expand the unpivoted column
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "unPivot", each 
            Table.UnpivotOtherColumns([Tables],{},"Type","Subtype")),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Tables"}),
    #"Expanded unPivot" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "unPivot", {"Type", "Subtype"}, {"Type", "Subtype"})
in
    #"Expanded unPivot"
```

[image]